# How to adjust textview's text size automatically to fill the layout it is in?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a (vertical)`LinearLayout` containing text inside a parent (vertical)`LinearLayout`. The text height is 50% of the parent view's height. The parent (vertical)`LinearLayout` fills the width of the screen and it's height is 33% of the screen's height (using `layout_weight`).

I want the text's size to adjust in order to fill the whole space provided to it. How can I achieve this? I have tried using `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` and making different values for each dpi category but it does not help.

All the text views in the (vertical)`LinearLayout` are

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

[image: The preview of the layout]

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using `layout_weight` and your parent `LinearLayout` has vertical orientation then your `layout_height` for children should be set on `0dp` not `wrap_content` for better performance. And inside that child can take `match_parent` for both.
Second one to support different screen sizes and densities then you will need to follow this guidance: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

But if you want some quick solution to change text size according to screen size then add this line of XML code to your `TextView`:

```
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
```

Android will try to adopt your `TextView` according to screen size. But anyway if you want different text sizes on different screens and densities then I'm afraid you will need to follow guidance above.